# Why the GetTextInRun() method stops at “ö”, “ü” or/and “ä”?

Tags: c#, wpf, find, richtextbox, rtf

I try to find a string (Placeholder) inside a RichTextBox (mark and replace it later). It works, but if there are `ö`,`ä` or `ü` the `GetTextInRun` cuts it in 2 or more parts.

```
TextRange text = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
TextPointer current = text.Start.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
while (current != null)
{
    string textInRun = current.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    //...
}
```

MSDN states:

> This method returns only uninterrupted runs of text. Nothing is
> returned if any symbol type other than Text is adjacent to the current
> `TextPointer` in the specified direction. Similarly, text is returned
> only up to the next non-text symbol.

So `öüä` is ***not a text***? But why is the result of the 2nd part not `ä` rather `äöü`?

A Placeholder looks like this: "[[$TabelleTyp1_test of tabletyp1]]" (always working), but can be "[[$TabelleTyp1_1. Hallo üch bin än Ümlütöst]]" (fail, textinRun: "[[$TabelleTyp1_1. Hallo üch bin än Ümlütö" - but after every Change in the rtf-file the result changes too ("[[$TabelleTyp1_1."). So I think there must be a invisible char who is breaking the "text" if a `öäü` inside the text? But I have no idea how I can ignore or remove this (random?) char(s?) without loosing the `TextPointer`)

BTW: "Detection" with regex works without any problems, so it can't be a "hidden" char?
regex: @"[[$TabelleTyp1_[a-zA-Z0-9 äöü.]*]]");

The only difference is for regex I use a forms `RichTextBox`, for selection/replacing ***[Xceed Toolkit](https://doc.xceed.com/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit%7EXceed.Wpf.Toolkit.RichTextBox.html)*** `RichTextBox` (WPF).

*Edit 1*: I copied the text.Text to clipboard and looked for hidden chars. There are no hidden chars, only `CR/LF` at end of lines.

*Edit 2*: "." was wrong, only `ö`,`ä` and `ü`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there is only one reason why the text in a paragraph is splitting into separate parts - **the context changing**. It happens when user change one of the following characteristics:

- The input language
- Font name
- Font style
- Foreground color
- Background color etc.

I am not considering the case when the partitioning can be done programmatically.
By the way, very easy to reproduce this problem in *MS Office Word*. Just type word **“tеst”** in English and then replace letter **“e”** from another language, for example, from German. Then run spelling check for the English. You will see an error. Visually everything is the same. But one word will be split into three `Run`'s. The *MS Word* will detect the letter from another language and will report the error.

> The problem described in this question is most likely the input
> language. See the following post describing a similar problem: [Edit
> RichTextBox Run element without splitting into multiple Run
> elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66087106/6630084).

**Solution 1:**

Try to set the input language in the `RichTextBox` control. Example, for German:

```xml
<RichTextBox x:Name="rtb" Language="de-de">
</RichTextBox>
```

Supported Culture Codes
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/common-parameters-and-types/supported-culture-codes

**Solution 2:**

If for some reasons the RTF-document already contains particular words split into different `Run`'s it is necessary to use context related methods to parse/analyze the `RichTextBox` content.

The example below demonstrates how it can be implemented.

*MainWindow.xaml:*

```xml
<Window ...
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="500">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RichTextBox Name="rtb" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Padding="5" Margin="10"
                     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                        <Run>Paste some document for testing and press the button below</Run>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>            
        </RichTextBox>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_SearchAsync" Margin="2" Padding="3">Press to search</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cs:*

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApp17
{    
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }    

        private async void Button_SearchAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await FindWordsAsync(rtb);
            rtb.Focus();
        }

        public async Task FindWordsAsync(RichTextBox rtb)
        {
            await Task<object>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var pairs = new Dictionary<string, SolidColorBrush>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                {
                    { "Rückvergrößerungsgeräten", Brushes.Blue },
                    { "Rückvergrößerungsgeräte", Brushes.DarkOrange },
                    { "Rückvergrößerungsgerät", Brushes.Red }
                };

                IList<KeyValuePair<string, TextRange>> ranges = null;

                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    // Define the range to be used to analyze for the specified words
                    var textRange = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);

                    // Build list of Word/TextRange pairs
                    ranges = textRange.CalculateTextRange(pairs.Select(d => d.Key).ToList());
                });

                // Color words by using calculated `TextRange`.
                for (int i = 0; i < ranges.Count; i++)
                {
                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { ranges[i].Value.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, pairs[ranges[i].Key]); });                    
                    //list[i].Value.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontSizeProperty, 20.0);                
                }
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

*TextRangeExt.cs:*

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace WpfApp17
{
    public static class TextRangeExt
    {
        public static IList<KeyValuePair<string, TextRange>> CalculateTextRange(this TextRange range, IList<string> words)
        {     
            // Building the regular expression pattern 
            var pattern = new StringBuilder(@"\b");
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0) pattern.Append('|');
                pattern.Append(words[i]);
            }
            pattern.Append(@"\b");
            var regExp = new Regex(pattern.ToString(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            int correction = 0;
            var result = new List<KeyValuePair<string, TextRange>>();
            TextPointer start = range.Start;

            // Enumerate all found mathes and creating list of Word/TextRange pairs
            foreach (Match match in regExp.Matches(range.Text))
            {
                if (CalculateTextRange(start, match.Index - correction, match.Length) is TextRange tr)
                {
                    result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, TextRange>(match.Value, tr));
                    correction = match.Index + match.Length;
                    start = tr.End;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        // Return calculated a `TextRange` of the string started from `iStart` index
        // and having `length` size or `null`.
        public static TextRange CalculateTextRange(TextPointer startSearch, int iStart, int length)
        {
            return (startSearch.GetTextPositionAtOffset(iStart) is TextPointer start)
                ? new TextRange(start, start.GetTextPositionAtOffset(length))
                : null;
        }

        public static TextPointer GetTextPositionAtOffset(this TextPointer position, int offset)
        {
            for (TextPointer current = position; current != null; current = position.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward))
            {
                position = current;
                var adjacent = position.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                var navigator = position.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                switch (navigator)
                {
                    case TextPointerContext.Text:
                        int count = position.GetTextRunLength(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                        if (offset <= count) return position.GetPositionAtOffset(offset);                        
                        offset -= count;
                        break;

                    case TextPointerContext.ElementStart:
                        if (adjacent is InlineUIContainer)
                        {
                            offset--;
                        }
                        else if (adjacent is ListItem lsItem)
                        {
                            var index = new TextRange(lsItem.ElementStart, lsItem.ElementEnd).Text.IndexOf('\t');
                            if (index >= 0) offset -= index + 1;
                        }                       
                        break;

                    case TextPointerContext.ElementEnd:
                        if (adjacent is Paragraph para)
                        {                          
                            var correction = 0;
                            if (para.Parent is TableCell tcell)
                            {
                                var bCount = tcell.Blocks.Count;
                                var cellText = new TextRange(tcell.Blocks.FirstBlock.ContentStart, tcell.Blocks.LastBlock.ContentEnd).Text;

                                if ((bCount == 1 && cellText.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine)) || bCount > 1) 
                                {
                                    correction = 2;
                                }
                                else if (tcell.Parent is TableRow trow)
                                {
                                    var cells = trow.Cells.Count;
                                    correction = (cells <= 0 || trow.Cells.IndexOf(tcell) != cells - 1) ? 1 : 2;
                                } 
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                correction = 2;
                            }
                            offset -= correction;
                        }                                        
                        break;
                }
            }
            return position;
        }
    }
}
```

To use the code above or for test purpose:

1. In the `FindWordsAsync()` method populate `pairs` with words to be found in the document. Set some color to be used to change words foreground if they  will be found. But most likely you do not need this functionality, used for the test, so you should change the code to leave only the list of required words.
2. The `List<KeyValuePair<string, TextRange>> CalculateTextRange(this TextRange range, IList<string> words)` method uses regular expression to find defined words. Therefore, part of this method can be changed depending on the text search criteria in the document.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, i will try it.Currently as a workaround i combine from 1 to a limit of 5 "GetTextInRun" by looping to one Word and check for the needed in every loop.